# How to solve unreleased lock issue in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

Someone please help me solve deadlock issues in c++ if possible with reference or examples.

Scenario would be like below.

Thread1 is locked by mutex and doing some operation, thread2 and thread3 are in waiting state for thread1 to unlock to access the resource.

Some abort/unexpected thing happened -- thread1 was terminated and didn't get the unlock, thread2 and thread3 are still waiting.

How to save the main thread (mean nothing should happen to main thread) in such situations.

Please throw some light how to solve such issues in c++.

Thanks,
Sheik

Comment: Can you show some code as to how you are utilising threads in c++ ?

Comment: What do you mean by "save the main thread"? Showing a small, compilable example of your code will be very helpful

Comment: Why the downvotes?? It's a valuable and serious question (may be beyond the downvoter's conception)!

Comment: This is not a deadlock. A deadlock is a circular chain of locks. This is simply an unreleased lock, i.e. a lock leak. The solution is the same as any other resource leak.

Comment: How about just fixing thread 1?

Answer (score 5):

> Some abort/unexpected thing happened

Use s.th. like [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) to prevent 'hanging' locks due to exceptions or forgotten/unexpected, but necessary `unlock()` operations.

The principle is pretty simple and you can easily implement it for any mechanism that uses a pair of methods that correspond together in a 'lock/unlock' manner:

```
class LockObject // E.g. mutex or alike
{
public:
    // ...
    void lock();
    void unlock();
};
```

Bind the guard classes constructor to a reference to the lock object's instance and call `lock()` in the constructor and `unlock()` in the destructor:

```
template<typename T>
class LockGuard
{
public:
    LockGuard(T& lockObject)
    : lockObject_(lockObject) 
    {
        lockObject_.lock();
    }
    ~LockGuard()
    {
        lockObject_.unlock();
    }

private:
    T& lockObject_;
};
```

Use `LockGuard` like this:

```
// Some scope providing 'LockObject lockObject'
{ LockGuard<LockObject> lock(lockObject)
    // Do s.th. when lockObject is locked
} // Call of lockObject.unlock() is guaranteed at least here, no matter what
  // (exception, goto, break, etc.) caused leaving the block's scope.
```

Comment: but will the destructor be called if the thread is **killed**

Comment: @RyanHaining If s.th. like a `thread::kill()` operation is available (OS-specific?) I'd expect it unwinding the stack correctly!

Comment: @RyanHaining Killing threads from the outside is a rather bad idea in C/C++. There's a reason why C++11's thread API won't allow this in the first place. The right way to terminate threads would be to implement a mechanism to signal the termination request and then allow the thread to shutdown by itself.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I'm aware that killing threads is a terrible thing to do, nonetheless, I think the question is that if a thread is killed while holding a mutex, is there a way to go about unlocking it?.  This is still a solid answer

Answer (score 2):

Generally threads should not terminate unexpectedly. You may try using try/catch blocks. If you still want to free resources when a thread terminates unexpectedly, you may create a monitor thread that waits for the termination of the first thread.

On Windows, you can use something as ::WaitForSingleObject(m_htThread, INFINITE).

Once the 1st thread had been terminated, you may proceed with freeing abandoned locks.
Maybe you'll want to add some flag which indicates if the termination was graceful.
You'll probably also have to remember which thread is locking which object.

As said, I wouldn't recommend using such method, but on extreme cases.

Answer (score -1):

The way to solve deadlocks in any language or platform is always the same.

Always acquire the locks in the same order.

**EDIT:** However you have misdescribed your problem. This is not a deadlock. A deadlock is a circular chain of locks. This is simply an unreleased lock, i.e. a lock leak. The solution is the same as any other resource leak: don't. In C++ that means releasing resources in destructors, and ensuring that destructors are called. Somehow your thread has terminated without doing that. Find *that* problem and fix it.

Comment: But his problem is that there is a single lock that isn't getting released, not that he's acquiring a second lock in the wrong order.  So this is not the correct solution in this case.

Comment: To whoever downvoted this: It's precisely right, but might not match the situation the OP described (I think it's simpler reason here).

Comment: @g-makulik obviously it's a correct statement, but it is irrelevant to the OPs question.  Any answer that didn't address that question would receive a downvote.  There is only one lock in this scenario.

Comment: @RyanHaining _'but it is irrelevant to the OPs question'_ Yes! You're right about this! But I anyway's think that it doesn't deserve a downvote. It's an important aspect handling deadlocks (which are at least mentioned in the questions title) correctly and might enlighten the OP down his path ;o) ...

Comment: @WanderingLogic In that case the problem isn't a deadlock at all.

Comment: @WanderingLogic I cannot follow this. If it isn't a deadlock it isn't relevant to my answer. I can't help what someone else would call it, non-'technically', and I don't find the speculation even slightly interesting. "Too cute" is a pretty strange description of a fundamental principle of concurrency. You don't know what I did and didn't read. You seem to be just wasting time here with all this extraneous matter.